# Blogger - внутренний API сайта

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

Помимо официального Blogger API (для которого существует документация) еще существует возможность получать посты и данные о них, с помощью внутренних AJAX-запросов на сайте.

Например, запрос к `URLсайта/feeds/posts/default?max-results=999&alt=json-in-script&callback=blog_archive_callback` вернет все посты (первые 999 постов, если точнее).

Мне интересно, можно ли сделать запрос с дополнительными параметрами, чтобы получить, например, только посты с определенными ярлыками или еще что.
Этакий 'недо-SQL'.

Да, я знаю, что Blogger это извращение. Но у меня крошечный сайт и нет желания тратить время на перенос на Wordpress.